# Instagram API Deprecation 2020 & Embedding API

Tags: instagram-api, deprecation-warning

I am consuming the following API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=#{instagram_post_url}
```

which is part of the Embed API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/embedding

I just want to be 100% sure, and hence posting this question, that this particular endpoint is not a part of the Legacy API that will be disabled at the end of this month, and there are no actions that need to be taken regarding this Instagram's API changes.

Ref: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything you find documented under `developers.facebook.com` is not part of the old IG legacy APIs to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this, Facebook is depreciating `https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=#{instagram_post_url}` for another API that is bricked behind an authentication wall on October 24 2020.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed